# WSO2 Api Manager Vs Ideniity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Can someone please clarify when to use API Manager and when to use Identity Server. I see that API Manager comes with Key Manager. Isn't that sufficient. I am really confused. Any help would be helpful.
Many thanks....

Answer (score 1):

I hope this explaination will help you out,

**WSO2 Identity Server**

WSO2 Identity Server is a fully fledged Identity Management Solution which supports Authentication, Authorization, Single Sign-On and Identity Federation to name a few capabilities. WSO2 Identity Server supports almost all major identity protocols such as SAML, OAuth2, OpenID Connect etc.Take a look at [this page](https://wso2.com/identity-and-access-management) to get an idea about the capabilities of WSO2 Identity Server.

**WSO2 API Manager**

WSO2 API Manager, on the other hand, focuses on managing your APIs. Managing life cycle of your APIs, Authorization, Throttling, applying policies on API consumers are some of the functionalities handled by API manager. API manager has several components such as publisher, store, gateway, key manager, traffic manager that clearly separates different aspects of API Management.

So the Key manager component is responsible for managing OAuth applications, generate, validate and revoke OAuth2 Tokens. API has an inbuilt key manager component to handle these functionalities.

API Manager also offers the flexibility to use an external key manager instead of its inbuilt one should you require to do so. This external key manager needs to confirm to an interface specified by API manager. By default, API has an implementation of this interface that allows WSO2 Identity Server to used an external key manager.

So whether or not you want to use Identity Server or any other external key manager is totally dependent on your use case and the API traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WSO2 Identity Server for all the authentication/authorization stuff:

1. XACML Architecture solution.
2. SSO with anothers webapps or WSO2 tools.
3. Implement a Oauth2 autorization mechanish
4. Federate authentication
5. etc....

You can uso WSO2 API Manager for expose unsecure resultful apis or webservices as secure apis using Oauth with monitoring and billings functionallities

The key manager functionallity properly decouples the operations for creating OAuth applications and validating access tokens so that you can even plug in a third party-authorization server for key validations.

In a DEV enviroment you can work with WSO2 API Manager without the WSO2 Identity Server at all.

In a production enviroment it's recommended to use a separate WSO2 API Manager as a Key Manager or use the WSO2 Identity Server as the Key Manager